# Problem with enter-pssession: "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set up PS Remoting/Win-RM and have the following:

```
$primary = 'server1'
$user = $env:UserName
$admUser = Get-Credential -UserName "domain\adm-$user" -Message 'Enter your *ADMIN* password:'

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $primary -Credential $admUser {
  hostname
}
```

However, this is returning the following error (I've tested this from a console and it works, so there's something wrong with my script):

```
Windows PowerShell credential request.
Enter your *ADMIN* password:
Password for user domain\adm-user1: ***************

Enter-PSSession : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '
hostname
'.
At line:5 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession  -ComputerName $primary -Credential $admUser {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` opens a console connection to a remote system.

If you want to run a command on a remote system, you'd want to use `Invoke-Command`.

Also, you 100% always need to pass scriptblocks into some parameter (minus some edge cases where it's accepted by default). In this case, we need to use `-Scriptblock`.

Example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $primary -Credential $admUser -ScriptBlock {
    hostname
}
```

or

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $primary -Credential $admUser

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {hostname}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$env:USERNAME}

Disconnect-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  That worked great.  Now, if I need to run a series of commands on the remote host, do I just keep issuing Invoke-Command or is there a way to establish a connection, then run the series of commands and disconnect?

Comment: You can use `New-PSSession` to create a $session variable, which you can then pass like this: `Invoke-Command -Session $session`. Invoke as many times as you need, then `Disconnect-PSSession -Session $session`. See my edit

Comment: Also if my answer answered your original question, please mark it answered by clicking the check mark to the left.

Comment: You saved my day.  Thank you very much for the thorough explanation.  Marked as answer.